# Android View : How to override padding from parent?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, padding

I have the following listView item (simplified):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/AppTheme.ListViewItemStyle_1">

    <View android:id="@+id/data_view_stripe"
        style="@style/AppTheme.RedStripe"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Style for list item has following padding:

```
<item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
```

Which should be applied to all contents except the:

```
<View android:id="@+id/data_view_stripe"
            style="@style/AppTheme.RedStripe"/>
```

How can i ovvrride this padding for data_view_stripe View please?

Many thanks for any advice.

**Edit:**

I tried to create child theme:

But it still produces padding for View with attached style
**RedStripeChild**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a child style

```
<style name="RedStripeChild" parent="AppTheme.RedStripe"> 
<item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item> 
<item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item> 
<item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: So maybe add padding in the view not in the style?